# Автозагрузка новых данных из textBox

Tags: c#

Программа отправляет 3 сообщения своим друзьям(список идентификаторов берётся из textBox6). Логины и пароли хранятся в отдельных файлах, на одинаковых позициях по отношению друг к другу. Логины прогружаются в textBox9, пароли в textBox13.

После того, как аккаунт отправляет 3 сообщения - происходит break и должен автоматически логиниться второй аккаунт, но этого не происходит, т.к. пароль берётся новый, а логин нет. почему? делаю так, использую VkNet

```
    void Go()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            foreach (var login in textBox9.Lines)
            {
                var log = login.ToString();
                foreach (var pas in textBox13.Lines)
                {

                    var passw = pas.ToString();

                    Send(log, passw);
                }
            }
        }
    }



    void Send(string logins, string pass)
    {
        int index = 0, count = 0;
        api.Authorize(4562540, logins, pass, Settings.All);


            foreach (var login in textBox6.Lines)
            {
                try
                {
                    var id = int.Parse(login);
                    textBox10.Text = api.Messages.Send(id, false, textBox12.Text).ToString();
                    label5.Text = "Отправлено: " + index.ToString();
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                    if (index++ == 2)
                    {
                        textBox11.Text = login;
                        label25.Text = "Кол-во отработавших аккаунтов: " + count.ToString();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот  этот кусок у Вас бежит по всем логинам, и для каждого логина пытается использовать **каждый** пароль

```
foreach (var login in textBox9.Lines)
{
    var log = login.ToString();
    foreach (var pas in textBox13.Lines)
    {
        var passw = pas.ToString();
        Send(log, passw);
    }
}
```

чтобы избежать такого используйте что-то вроде:

```
for (var i = 0; i < textBox9.Lines; i++)
{
    var log = textBox9.Lines[i].ToString();
    var passw = textBox13.Lines[i].ToString();
    Send(log, passw);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Это решило мою проблему.